# Filter People and Group column using [Me]

Tags: list, filter, people-search

Our list has a people and group column (called Users) which we want to filter using [Me]. It works when the field only contains individual users, but when the field contains a group (either SP group or AD group) then rows for which [Me] is a member of the group it fails to match.

Here is an example:

```
ID  | Users

1   | John; Bill
2   | Accounting
3   | Engineering
```

Assuming that John is an engineer, I would expect the filter using [Me] (when John is using it) to return rows 1 and 3 (because John is part of the Engineering Active Directory group), but alas only row 1 is returned.

Is this behavior possible when declaring a view over this list? Or do I need to resort to a CAML query (example?), or even a web service which will interact with Active Directory to resolve John's membership in the Engineering and Accounting groups.

Answer (score 2):

I think below link is what you are looking to achieve
[Click here](http://www.hornerit.com/2009/07/filtering-by-group-in-sharepoint-person.html)!

Also please check out the technet article link in that post.

Hope this helps

Cheers!

Comment: Looks to be the solution. I will accept once I was able to reproduce the result. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you out

http://alottolearn.net/2011/11/28/filter-active-tasks-by-me-and-me-as-group-member/

here is how it would be done using the Membership Element in CAML:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
    <And>
     <Neq>
      <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
      <Value Type="Text">Completed</Value>
     </Neq>
     <Or>
      <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
        <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
      </Membership>
      <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
       <Value Type="Integer">
         <UserID Type="Integer"/>
       </Value>
      </Eq>
     </Or>
    </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Link is broken now

Comment: please refer this: https://alottolearndotnet.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/filter-active-tasks-by-me-and-me-as-group-member/ as well updated answer with full code for future reference