# how to filter task items which is assigned to a particular person?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a task list based on event content type. In that list I have a column named "Assigned to" which is a person or group field. I am assigning to a group. I want to create a view of this task list which has to show the items assigned to the current user. I have tried with filter using [Me] option.But no use.

Pls. suggest.

Comment: Check this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49308/filter-people-and-group-column-using-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by making few changes to the sharepoint page using designer, once you have put [Me] filter on the task list open page in designer and locate the Query of the view and modify as below

`<Query>
<Where>
<Or>
<And>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value>
</Eq>
<IsNull>
<FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
</IsNull>
</And>
<And>
<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/></Membership>
<IsNull>
<FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
</IsNull>
</And>
</Or>
</Where>
</Query`

refer [this](http://www.makdeniz.com/how-to-filter-sharepoint-2010-tasks-which-are-assigned-to-you-and-the-group-your-are-member-of/#!lightbox/3/) link for detailed steps.